# $http.post triggered only on the last loop on angular.forEach

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a problem making an $http.post request on a forEach loop in angularjs. Only on the last loop (obj.dtype == 'Install') that the $http.post is triggered. How do i able to make the $http.post work on every loop?

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(obj, i){
  if(obj.dtype == 'Remove'){
    $http.post('url1').success();
  } else if(obj.dtype == 'Install'){
    $http.post('url2').success();
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

**Solution:**

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(obj, i){
  if(obj.dtype == 'Remove'){
    url = 'url1';
    dataToUpload = {};
  } else if(obj.dtype == 'Install'){
    url = 'url2'
    dataToUpload = {};
  }

 $http.post(url, dataToUpload).success();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with AngularJs `$http` POST call.
Following code works for me where the POST is fired four times.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.data = ["Data1","Data2","Data3","Data4"]

  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(obj, i){
    $http({method:'POST', url: 'http://httpbin.org/post', data: obj}).
        success(function(data, status) {
          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.data = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
      });
  });
}]);
```

I would suggest reviewing content of `$scope.data` and the syntax of `$http`.

Comment: Does the if statement inside the foreach loop might be the factor? Having 2 $http request for post depending on what type the value in the data will be.

Comment: I tried putting a console.log on the if statement to determine if it is being read and not being bypassed. I got responsed on the console and it is just the $http.post was somehow not being fired not until it is the last data.

Comment: try using `$http({})` syntax instead of `.post` method. can you add the code given above in your controller and run? Also if possible provide the exact code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I haven't stared at it too long I won't figured it out.